# Data types in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working with OpenCV for the first time and I'm a little bit confused with data types. **I am working with Python.**

I see that I can store an image as:

- Numpy array
- CvMat
- Iplimage

The problem I'm having is that different parts of OpenCV seem to require different types and I keep having to try and convert back and forth- it's very confusing, and I'm certain it can't have been designed this way on purpose. I'm also a bit confused about when something should be in the cv module vs cv2.cv:

```
import cv
import cv2.cv
```

Can someone explain the logic? It would really help.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the Python api well, but for a start at least you probably want to just use `cv2.cv`. `cv` is the older interface that you should try to stay away from. Iplimage is also part of this older image so you want to avoid using that format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- cv  (or, cv2.cv)

  is the *old* opencv python api, using IplImage and CvMat.

  you should not use that anymore. it's being phased out, and won't be available in the next version.
- cv2 is the *new* python api, using numpy arrays for almost anything instead,

  so easy to combine with scipy, matplotlib and what not. (and , btw, much closer the the current c++ api)

Comment: This is very good to know. I've noticed though quite a few things aren't available under cv2- for example, cv2.logPolar ?

Comment: Here's another: cv2.cv.CV_RGB(0, 255, 0)

Comment: @cjm2671, - you don't need it. i's just a tuple with cv2/numpy, - (0,255,0)

Comment: `>>> import cv2
>>> help(cv2.logPolar)
logPolar(...)
    logPolar(src, center, M, flags[, dst]) -> dst`